# How to pass anchor tag class Id to a function variable using mvc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to pass anchor tag class name `ID` to a function var `ID` where var `variable ID` value should be passed in to the `@Url.Action("pharmaCompanyDetails", "PharmaCompany", new { pharmaID = ID })`

Variable `ID` value this passed into the `pharmaID`

Code:

```
<a class="detail" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Detail"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></a>
```

Button Click

```
'click .detail': function (e, value, row, index) {
                alert('You click like action, row: ' + JSON.stringify(row.id));
                var ID = JSON.stringify(row.id);
                window.location.href = '@Url.Action("pharmaCompanyDetails", "PharmaCompany", new { pharmaID = ID })';
            },
```

[image: ID]

Comment: `var ID = JSON.stringify(row.id);` is javascript (client side code). `@Url.Action()` is server side code - `location.href = '@Url.Action("pharmaCompanyDetails", "PharmaCompany") + '?pharmaID=' + ID;`

Comment: Why are you using `JSON.stringify()?` It should be just `var ID = row.ID`

Comment: yes now i am used  var ID = row.ID getting all records from ID value@StephenMuecke

Comment: output after i added your code http://localhost:51426/PharmaCompany/pharmaCompanyDetails%20+%20'?pharmaID=4      **%20+%20** @StephenMuecke

Comment: Sorry, I missed a `'` after `Url.Action()` - `'@Url.Action("pharmaCompanyDetails", "PharmaCompany")' + '?pharmaID=' + ID;`

Comment: this code is working location.href = "@Url.Action("pharmaCompanyDetails", "PharmaCompany")?pharmaID=" + ID; @Stephen Muecke

Comment: thanks @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this code is working

```
location.href = "@Url.Action("pharmaCompanyDetails", "PharmaCompany")?pharmaID=" + ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"@Url.Action("pharmaCompanyDetails", "PharmaCompany")"
```

is rendered, server-side, by Razor and all your MVC firepower.
When you land on the page it is already replaced by the url of your choice.

javascripts instead works on the client side, so it receive the id only when you click the button, long after your server side elaboration.

So,

```
'@Url.Action("pharmaCompanyDetails", "PharmaCompany", new { pharmaID = ID })'
```

ID cannot be used as a parameter inside this for this reason.

So you have to attach the ID to the end of the url, as you said:

```
location.href = "@Url.Action("pharmaCompanyDetails", "PharmaCompany")?pharmaID=" + ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
location.href = "@Url.Action("actionname", "controller")?pharmaID=" + ID;
```

this c# code

```
@Url.Action("actionname", "controller")
```

will be converted to

```
controller/actionname
```

so full url will be

```
controller/actionname?pharmaID=ID;
```